# Ruby generated javascript file is not updated on page refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I am working on an application where items stored in database are displayed on Google map. For that purpose I added `gmap.js.erb` file to `app/assets/javascripts` folder. Items are fetched from the corresponding table and put on the map in the following way:

```
function showItemsOnMap() {
  <% Item.all.each do |item| %>
    var lat = <%= item.lat %>;
    var lng = <%= item.lng %>;
    addMarker(lat, lng);
  <% end %>
}
```

This works fine and items are displayed correctly, but when I add a new item and refresh my map page, the newly added item is not displayed. `gmap.js.erb` is not updated after I make changes to the database and click refresh. I guess it is not enough to trigger `gmap.js.erb` update just by clicking refresh button in the browser. How should I do that? How one makes `gmap.js.erb` updated whenever Items table is modified?

Comment: What does you console log/network panel say? Do you get an 304(Not modified) response? Are there any errors that might have occured after an item should have been added?

Comment: Did you turn off Turbolinks? http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4 and restart

Comment: @Kalman turning off Turbolinks didn't help.

Comment: @Blauharley items are added, modified and deleted without any errors. If I restart server they are displayed on the map correctly.

Comment: This is what it sounds like to me. The server generates the showItemsOnMap() method and sends it to the client (browser). The method is called on the client, but the client never goes back to the server to ask for more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gmap.js.erb is compiled to gmap.js and cached at the time of first page request which uses this js file. You can put these js inside view to make it a dynamic script.

view.html.erb

```
<script>
function showItemsOnMap() {
  <% Item.all.each do |item| %>
    var lat = <%= item.lat %>;
    var lng = <%= item.lng %>;
    addMarker(lat, lng);
  <% end %>
}
</script>
```